# Regular Expressions - Capture all from X until the next Y

Tags: php, regex

I'm having some trouble with a regular expression in PHP. What I'm trying to achieve is to have placeholder tokens within a string which are then replaced with a value.

I'm using the following syntax.

> `Hello {{ username }}! Your order ID is {{ order }}.`

Having little experience with regular expressions, I used Regex101 an online regular expression test environment and came up with the following expression.

```
({{(?:.*?)(?:property)(?:.*?)}})
```

Which worked fine, until I used more than one token on a single line and realised a huge flaw in the expression. I understand how the expression is evaluating and have labeled the image below with my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong).

[image]

I'd like to think I'm not far away from what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm at a loss so any help is appreciated.

There needs to be a property name within the token that is included in the pattern, in the image above the property is `email`.

Thanks for any help!

**Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/7Ezep5/1**

Comment: @chris85 - I've updated the post with a link to the Regex101 example.

Comment: May I ask why you're using this awful syntax instead of just using proper, regular PHP variables?

Comment: You could do something like https://regex101.com/r/7Ezep5/2 then use `preg_replace_callback` and check if the value is your property.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - The strings are going to be parsed in an environment where PHP variables wouldn't necessary suffice. They're extending a basic markdown esque templating language, however, the values referenced in the tokens are being interpolated based on a php object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:

`.` matches anything (but new line). Change it to `[^}]` meaning anything but `}`. Like

```
({{(?:[^}]*?)(?:email)(?:[^}]*?)}})
```

I.e. if it doesn't find the string `email` before a `}`, it fails.

[Check this updated regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7Ezep5/3).

Comment: Actually, it would also need to match the property name perfectly not inclusively. So, in the Regex101 example, it shouldn't match `contact_email`, but would match a token with `email` as the property. How would I achieve this?

Comment: I managed to get what I'm trying to achieve by modifying your answer to the following: `({{(?:[^}]*?)\b(?:email)\b(?:[^}]*?)}})`.

Comment: Good. But if the part between the braces solely consist of the property property, you could skip the `(?:[^}]*?)` parts. Or if spaces are to be allowed (not mandatory), change it to `\s*`. I.e. `({{email}})` or `({{\s\*email\s\*}})`.